# A bootstrap from the traditional version of Transfinite Recursion to the parametric one

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

I'm self-learning Transfinite Recursion Theorem and its variants from textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech.

After the authors have presented proofs of theorems **4.9**, **4.10**, and **4.11**, they conclude *A parametric version of Theorem 4.11 is straightforward and we leave it to the reader*.

I have tried to give it a shot, but I'm not sure if it's fine or not. Does my attempt look fine or contain flaws? I'm very pleased to receive suggestion!

---

> Let $V$ be the class of all sets, $\operatorname{Ord}$ be the class of all ordinals, and $G:V\to V$ be a class function.

**Theorem 4.9: Transfinite Recursion Theorem**

> There exists a class function $F$ such that $F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction \alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$.

**Theorem 4.10: Transfinite Recursion Theorem, Parametric Version**

> There exists a class function $F$ such that $F(z,\alpha)=G(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$ and $z\in V$ where $F_z\restriction \alpha:=\{\langle\beta,F(z,\beta)\rangle\mid\beta<\alpha\}$.

**Theorem 4.11:**

> Let $G_1,G_2,G_3$ be class functions from $V$ to $V$. There exists a class function $F$ such that
>
> (1) $F(0)=G_1(\emptyset)$
>
> (2) $F(\alpha+1)=G_2(F(\alpha))$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$
>
> (3) $F(\alpha)=G_3(F\restriction\alpha)$ for all limit $\alpha\neq 0$

---

**My attempt:**

We define the class function $G:V\to V$ as follows

- $G(x)=G_1(z,\emptyset)$ for $x=(z,0)$
- $G(x)=G_2(z,f(\alpha))$ for $x=(z,f)$ where $f$ is a function with $\operatorname{dom}f=\alpha+1\in\operatorname{Ord}$
- $G(x)=G_2(z,f)$ for $x=(z,f)$ where $f$ is a function with $\operatorname{dom}f=\alpha$ for a limit $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$
- $G(x)=\emptyset$ for $x$ is none of the above

By **Theorem 4.10**, there exists a class function $F$ such that $F(z,\alpha)=G(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$. Thus we have

$F(z,0)=G(z,F_z\restriction 0)=G(z,0)=G_1(z,\emptyset)$

$F(z,\alpha+1)=G(z,F_z\restriction \alpha+1)=G_2(z,F_z(\alpha))$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$

$F(z,\alpha)=G(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)=G_3(z,F_z\restriction\alpha)$ for all limit $\alpha\neq 0$

This completes the proof.